# Order of Monitor regain in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, monitor

Well, I was wrong - the stating below does not apply, not in my test runs.

---

This mail ([wot, no chickens?)](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/projects/ofa/java-threads/0.html) from the the Java Thread mailing list is quite old, in fact it's from 25th September 1996. Peter Welch has found out:

> Enclosed is a demonstration that shows that **notified threads** do get
>   put on the *back* of the queue **in order to regain the monitor**.  Before
>   the `wait' method returns, **the thread is made to queue up again** on the
>   monitor (**behind threads that arrived long after it** first went through
>   that queue!). This can result in infinite overtaking and, hence,
>   thread starvation.

To summarize the behavior again:

```
Thread-1 acquires the monitor lock
Thread-1 sees the condition is not true yet -> wait()
Thread-0 acquires the monitor lock
Thread-2 contends with Thread-0 for the monitor lock
Thread-3 contends with Thread-0 for the monitor lock
Thread-4 contends with Thread-0 for the monitor lock
Thread-5 contends with Thread-0 for the monitor lock
Thread-0 turns the condition to true -> notifyAll();
Thread-0 released the monitor lock
Thread-4 acquires the monitor lock
Thread-4 enjoys his desirable state
Thread-4 releases the monitor lock
Thread-2 acquires the monitor lock
Thread-2 enjoys his desirable state
...
```

The thread being the first one to wait on the condition will **never** be the first one to regain the monitor. I knew already, that there is no fairness guarantee. What, however, is new to me, is that there is some kind of order in how the threads regain the monitor.

Why should the first thread be the one to regain the monitor lock the last? The way it's implemented `Thread-1` is never able to pass the condition and get into the desired state.

Is there some explanation for this semantic?

**Important:** This question is not about, **whether I can rely** on the mechanics I've discovered. I know how the waiting and signalling for Java is documented and that they clearly state, **you cannot rely on this**. What I am interested in, whether virtual machines implement it in this way, whether they order the threads in this certain way.

Comment: If I implement a JVM I will make number 3 go last, I don't like that number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordering is going to be JVM specific if you are using Object's wait/notify. The javadoc for the notify method states:

```
Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor. If any threads are
waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened. The choice is arbitrary and 
occurs at the discretion of the implementation. A thread waits on an object's monitor by 
calling one of the wait methods.
```

However, a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` does support a fairness policy, and fair mode is described as:

```
When constructed as fair, threads contend for entry using an approximately arrival
order policy. When the currently held lock is released either the longest-waiting
single writer thread will be assigned the write lock, or if there is a group of reader
threads waiting longer than all waiting writer threads, that group will be assigned the read lock.
```

Comment: I am sorry, I know how waiting and signalling is documented, I have added a note to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to check the documentation, but it was my understanding that there is no guarantee of which thread among several contenders will get the lock. It's not "first in first out" or any such deterministic ordering. If you want function X to execute before function Y, then don't create two separate threads. Create one thread that executes X, then executes Y. The whole idea of multi-threading is that all these threads run independently. If you are asking, "How can I insure that thread-1 runs before thread-2?", you're asking the wrong question. If the code in thread-1 must run before the code in thread-2, then don't make them two separate threads. It's like the old joke, Patient: "Doctor, every time I hold my arm above my head like this, I get this terrible pain." Doctor: "So don't hold your arm above your head like that."